# Name of the probability distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, moment-problem

If $X\sim N(0,1)$, then the density function of random variable $X^3$ is as follows:
$$f(y)=\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2\pi}}\left | y \right |^{-\frac{2}{3}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left | y \right |^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$
I'm interested in the properties of this distribution. I could derive them, but maybe it has some special name, so I could search for it specifically.
So, my question, what is the name of the above distribution with the above pdf?

Comment: I think this is an exercise for finding E(X), Var(X), and so on. Not every function of a normal distribution has practical uses or a specific name. I don't think it helps for what you want to do, but you might look at Wikipedia 'exponential family of distributions."

Comment: It's not a homework exercise. The expecation and variance calculations are almost trivial. I am not interested in that. I needed information about the particular type of distribution, i.e. the name of it (if it exists).
This distribution popped out in a research context. More specifically I have a weighted sum of random variables $Y_i=X_i^3$, where $X$ has a standard distribution.

Comment: OK. See my Comment about the exponential family, and maybe others have additional info.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo Yes, the exponential family seems to the the bes I can get. Distribution i;m interested probably has no significant value to be worthy of some specific name

Answer (score 1):

An explicit derivation of Robert Israel's claim is fairly straightforward by induction:  $$\begin{align*}  \operatorname{E}[X^{2m}] &= \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty x^{2m} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx \end{align*}$$ and with the choice $$u = x^{2m-1}, \quad du = (2m-1) x^{2(m-1)} \, dx, \quad dv = x e^{-x^2/2} \, dx, \quad v = -e^{-x^2/2},$$ we obtain $$\begin{align*} \operatorname{E}[X^{2m}] &= \left[ -\frac{x^{2m-1} e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \right]_{x=-\infty}^\infty + (2m-1)\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty x^{2(m-1)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx \\ &= (2m-1)\operatorname{E}[X^{2(m-1)}]. \end{align*}$$  Since $\operatorname{E}[X^0] = 1$, we obtain $$\operatorname{E}[X^{2m}] = \prod_{j=1}^m (2j-1) = (2m-1)!! = \frac{(2m)!}{2^m m!}.$$

Comment: Glad this wasn't put on hold as 'not clear'. We're having too much fun with it regardless what OP really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Extended comment.

Here is a simulation experiment (in R), that suggests $Var(X^3) = 15.$

```
 x = rnorm(10^6);  y = x^3
 var(y);  mean(abs(y) < 40)
 ## 15.02577;  0.999341
 summary(y)
 ##        Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
 ##  -1.020e+02 -3.077e-01  1.118e-08 -2.277e-04  3.101e-01  1.409e+02 

  hist(y[abs(y)< 40], prob=T, br=50, col="wheat", main="")
  curve(1/(3*sqrt(2*pi))*abs(x)^(-(2/3))*exp(-.5*abs(x)^(2/3)),
      lwd=2, n = 1001, col="blue", add=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Variance of $X^3$ (when mean of $X^3$ is $0$) is $E[X^6]$.  For standard normal, the even-numbered moments are $1, 1, 3, 15, 105, 945, 10395, \ldots$ (the "double factorials", http://oeis.org/A001147 ).

Comment: Nice. Better than a simulation. Also MGFs might be more useful for what OP wants. Mainly, I wanted to illustrate for OP that the PDF is right.